# how to add horizontal wheel selector in ionic 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, selector

I'm working on a ionic2 project and I need to select number using horizontal scroll wheel [image: design for wheel selector]

But I could find thing native for this. I have tried ***@ionic-native/wheel selector*** but it doesn't work this way, it open a modal type to select number. 
I tried to make my own custom roller using some tags

```
<ion-grid>
                <ion-row class="overflow-x">
                    <ion-col *ngFor="let number of number_array;"><h2>{{ number }}</h2>    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
```

it look like same as required and scoll horizontal as well but not able to select and magnify middle value

[image]

Please show some solution to achieve this?

Comment: We did same like that using ion-slide

Comment: Please check https://github.com/jasonmamy/cordova-wheel-selector-plugin#results

Comment: @PareshGami can you please share some more information, like how you achieve this

Comment: @AshishDetroja this create a modal type effect, that i have already achieved. i need to show on main page only

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: @Orochi yea but I didn't find a standard way of doing that. so I used 
 a trick to get my job done. I used a div with fixed width also fixed the width of each number then I calculate the percentage of the horizontal scroll and got the value of the selected number.